# Parse css with PHP

Tags: php, css, parsing

I am currently running into a little problem with a project. I am getting HTML files with CURL and unfortunately when images are set as background image in the css they won't load of course because i don't have the images on my server. So I need to "rewrite" the CSS to point to the correct locations. But I was not able to find anything on this using google. any help would be greatly appreciated :)!

I think I found a way to do it gonna try it out now.

Get all the background attributes with something like this

```
var backgroundStuff = [
  "background-image",
  "background"
];

var props = $("a").css( backgroundStuff );
alert(props["background"]);
```

And ten check if they are images and not colors of something else and then make ajax calls for every image.

Comment: Can you post some code to illustrate the problem?

Comment: @WyattEarp The code is just a default CURL function and echoing its result it works fine. and now i need to rewrite the background url attributes to be changed from /example/img/example.png to http://domain.com/example/img/example.png so the image can get resolved

Answer (score 0):

So your question is a bit broad to get a full anwer in this forum but what your doing is not unlike a minification operation. Minifying compiles css from many files into one file and must rewrite the urls to match the new path.

Check out the library https://code.google.com/p/cssmin/ and the function extract_data_urls